# PHP SELECT QUERY TOP 10

Tags: php, hashtag

```
SELECT SUBSTR(message, LOCATE('#', message)) message
FROM t_haps_wall
WHERE message like '%#%'
```

The query is ok and now I want to set top 10 hashtag.

So how can I set that ?
Thanks for help/

Comment: What do you mean by **setting top 10 hashtag** ? You want to select the first 10 rows with hashtags?

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good except for the `AS`, where we represent something (in this case a `SUBSTR`), **AS** something else.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(`message`, LOCATE('#', `message`)) AS `message`
FROM `t_haps_wall`
WHERE `message` LIKE '%#%'
ORDER BY `YOUR_COLUMN_OF_ORDER` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: seems like 'message' is a table attribute... probably don't want to reuse that name specifically

Comment: Your right, I just threw some "`" around them to make them work

Comment: In my case, if there are same hashtag it will show all.. How can I set if same hash, it will count and show just in 1 hashtag ?

Answer (score 0):

It first of all depends on what is the criteria for your top 10 rows. If lets say your ranking based on some column within your table you can do order by it and then set a limit something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(message, LOCATE('#', message)) message
FROM t_haps_wall
ORDER BY somePopularityColumn DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: In my case, if there are same hashtag it will show all.. How can I set if same hash, it will count and show just in 1 hashtag ?

Comment: you could use some sort of grouping statement

Answer (score 0):

Here we Go...

```
SELECT SUBSTR(message, LOCATE('#', message)) message FROM t_haps_wall WHERE message like '%#%' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You can also change its order in ascending or descending by using "order by ASC|DESC" in your query